# Jupyter Notebook in VSCode entering new line in a cell is slow

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, vscode-extensions

recently I have switched from Jupyter that I open in a browser (I was using Anaconda back then) to Jupyter in a VSCode and if for example I have 20 cells and decide to change something in 10th (so there are 10 cells of code/markdowns benath it), it takes so much time to create new line.

For example after writing `if x == 5:` and pressing enter to create and go to new line under `if` I do not create new line and go to that line in a moment. Instead of that it takes my sometimes even 5 seconds of waiting after hitting (multiple times) enter until new line (one) appears.

When I'm in a last cell creating new lines of code takes no time.

Has anyone encountered such problem? Is it fixable without taking code from 10th cell to last, rewriting it there and taking it back to 10th?

Comment: I am facing the same problem and I submitted a bug report, you might want to follow it here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/13379